# How to bind managedContextObject to an array controller

Tags: cocoa, binding, nsarraycontroller, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have two xib's, in each xib i have array controllers.Now i want to bind managedObjectContext to arraycontroller in another/ 2nd xib which i have created explicitly. When i run the app am getting an exception saying "this class is not key value coding-complaint for the managedObjectContext".

Comment: You need to tell us more about the binding(s). Please tell us each bound object, which binding you have bound, what object you have bound it to, the controller key, and the model key path—all of this for **every** binding.